# Apply SCSS Style sheets conditionally for light and dark mode in React component

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a react component that needs to apply an scss sheet conditionally based on a toggle.

The component looks like this.

```
export const ThemeProvider =({children}) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  console.log('Theme from themeProvider', theme);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === 'light') {
      import('./AppLight.scss');
    } else {
      import('./AppDark.scss');
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return <AppContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>; 
}
```

I want to change the theme based on the theme value. This works initially, but it does not switch back to light mode. This doesn't seem the correct way to do this, but I haven't used SCSS before. Is there a better way to do this than conditionally importing the SCSS?

Answer (score 1):

it works initially because initially there is only one css file imported and with change in state of `theme` previous import won't go away.

in this type of use case it would be better to use css modules using which you can dynamically change classes without any issues.